# when i install npm -g @angular/cli then get this error

Tags: angular, installation

> node -v
>
> v9.2.1
>
> npm -v
>
> 5.5.1
>
> npm install -g @angular cli

then get this error `.ESOCKETTIMEDOUT`

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
     try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

```
 export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
```

or configure npm proxy via

```
 npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

Any guys please help me

Comment: Please try setting `HTTPS_PROXY` or `npm config set https-proxy`

Comment: if you are sitting behind the corporate firewall, please ask your network admin about the proxy. Or switch the network to an open firewall free network may be your personal n/w from your dongle or cell phone. And then try

Answer (score 0):

```
 1) Install node.js and check and node -v in command prompt. (Node.js 
       through website).
2) npm install -g @angular/cli@latest (run in command prompt).
Refer this link for further help
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

    3) Check node -version
    4) Check npm -version
    5) check ng -version
```

If already installed, then uninstall it and install again,

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
```